# scheduling jobs to clustered quartz1.8.6 from non-cluster configured quartz scheduler instance

Tags: jdbc, locking, mixing, contention, quartz

I'm using quartz 1.8.6 in clustered mode with 4 instances. Now, I observed high contention on table QRTZ_LOCKS. My application also provide webservices for online clients. This webservices also do scheduling of new jobs. Now, I see timeout exceptions on those webservices, because when they want to schedule new job they wait too loooong to obtain lock on QRTZ_LOCKS table. It's important for me to establish 100% reliable operation for webservices (more important than quartz jobs operations). Is it possible to start quartz job runner on 1 instance only and other 3 instances configure with org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false to allow them perform scheduling WITHOUT getting lock on QRTZ_LOCKS?

update: Actually, if I plan to run only one instance with job runner and all others just allowed to add new jobs this won't be a cluster anymore. So, actual question would be: is it possible to configure org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false to all 4 instances, make only 1 instance run jobs, but allow all 4 to schedule new jobs to same jdbc storage?

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn batch mode on, and set maximum batch count to the amount of threads, available for quartz scheduler.

http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2016/01/14/performance-tuning-on-quartz-scheduler/